# Order by date different columns

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm having a problem with a complex SELECT, so I hope some of you can help me out, because I'm really stuck with it... or maybe you can point me in a direction.

I have a table with the following columns:

```
score1, gamedate1, score2, gamedate2, score3, gamedate3
```

Basically I need to determine the ultimate winner of all the games, who got the SUMMED MAX score FIRST, based on the game times in ASCENDING order.

Comment: If possible, you should have instead "score, gamedate, number" this will be a lot easier to do queries.

Comment: Anything specific you're having trouble with? [Do you have an attempt at a query we can look at?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @the_lotus: hi, thx for the tip!, will try your approach next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 1,2,3 are different players, something like this should work:

```
-- construct table as the_lotus suggests
WITH LotusTable AS
(
    SELECT 'P1' AS Player, t.Score1 AS Score, t.GameDate1 as GameDate
        FROM Tbl t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P2' AS Player, t.Score2 AS Score, t.GameDate2 as GameDate
        FROM Tbl t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P3' AS Player, t.Score3 AS Score, t.GameDate3 as GameDate
        FROM Tbl t
)
-- get running scores up through date for each player
, RunningScores AS 
(
    SELECT b.Player, b.GameDate, SUM(a.Score) AS Score
    FROM LotusTable a
            INNER JOIN LotusTable b -- self join
                ON a.Player = b.Player
                    AND a.GameDate <= b.GameDate -- a is earlier dates
        GROUP BY b.Player, b.GameDate
)
-- get max score for any player
, MaxScore AS 
(
    SELECT MAX(r.Score) AS Score
        FROM RunningScores r
)
-- get min date for the max score
, MinGameDate AS 
(
    SELECT MIN(r.GameDate) AS GameDate
        FROM RunningsScores r
        WHERE r.Score = (SELECT m.Score FROM MaxScore m)
)
-- get all players who got the max score on the min date
    SELECT * 
        FROM RunningScores r
        WHERE r.Score = (SELECT m.Score FROM MaxScore m)
            AND r.GameDate = (SELECT d.GameDate FROM MinGameDate d)
;
```

There are more efficient ways of doing it; in particular, the self-join could be avoided.

Comment: Dear Marc!
Thx for the effort you've made helping me out of this situation! I'll try your solution!

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are set up three columns: player_id, score1, time

Then you would just need a simple query to sum their scores and group them by player_ID as follows:

```
SELECT gamedata1.player_ID as 'Player_ID', 
   sum(gamedata1.score1 + gamedata2.score1 + gamedata3.score1) as 'Total_Score'

FROM gamedata1 
 LEFT JOIN gamedata2 ON (gamedata1.player_ID = gamedata2.player_ID)
 LEFT JOIN gamedata3 ON (gamedata1.player_ID = gamedata3.player_ID)

GROUP BY 'player_ID'

ORDER BY time ASC
```

Explanation:
You are essentially grouping by each player so you can get a distinct player in each row, and then summing their scores and organizing the data in this fashion.  I put the "time" as a date type.  The can be changed of coarse to any datetype, etc that you would prefer.  The structure of the query would be the same.

Comment: You are close... read the question again -- he wants the sums to change the order